# Django modify objects using key=value options

Tags: python, django, datatables

I'm doing http POST processing of incoming data modifications requests (from a DataTables table) for objects in my Django environment. The POST data comes to me in key=value pairs.

The problem I'm running into is that I haven't found a way to turn this into something I can use. Django objects and modifications are done like this:

```
id = 123
item = Stuff.objects.get(id=id)
item.title = "New Title"
item.save()
```

I have the following data attributes:

```
id = 123
attribute = "title" 
value = "New Title"
```

How can I use them to modify a Django object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient way to do this is with:

```
id = 123
attribute = 'title'
value = 'New Title'
Stuff.objects.filter(id=id).update(**{attribute: value})
```

This will prevent first fetching the object with a query, and then update it.

If you need to load the object anyway, you can work with [**`setattr(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
id = 123
attribute = 'title'
value = 'New Title'

item = Stuff.objects.get(id=id)
setattr(item, attribute, value)
item.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an if statement like

```
If attribute = 'title'
    item.title = value
    item.save()
```